# add-hook evil-insert-state-entry-hook is not calling the function

Tags: evil, hooks

Update: It worked properly somehow after disabling and enabling nyan-mode. 
**BUT** there is no evidence indicating any relationship between them. Because I can't reproduce this problem after it was magically fixed.

My suspicion is that if the -- INSERT -- can show properly then the hook can be called properly. And if not it can't. Because I don't remember seeing -- INSERT -- when the problem exists. But again there is no evidence. Just for someone who might encounter this problem some day.

---

I have following code in my init.el (actually .spacemacs but you know what I mean). I try to invoke function input-switch-use-method1 when I enter insert mode in evil

```
;; switch input method when toggling insert mode
  (setq input-switch-method0 "com.apple.keyboardlayout.all")
  (setq input-switch-method1 "com.apple.inputmethod.SCIM")

  (defun input-switch-use-method (method)
    (when 'input-switch-is-on
      (shell-command (replace-regexp-in-string "method" method "swim use method"))))

  (defun input-switch-activate () (interactive) (setq input-switch-is-on t))

  (defun input-switch-use-method1 () (interactive) (input-switch-use-method input-switch-method1))

  (add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'input-switch-activate)

  (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook 'input-switch-use-method1)
```

When I call `input-switch-use-method1` directly from M-x it works, but entering insert mode by pressing `i` does not do anything.

I found no information indicating this hook being defective. 
Does anyone know why and how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a hook has been called by adding something like `(message "Test")` to it.  This will show that it has indeed been called.  One issue here is that `(when 'input-switch-is-on ...)` will always evaluate to true because you're checking whether a symbol is not nil, rather than whether the variable has a non-nil value.  You'll have to do more systematic debugging because if I replace the `shell-command` call with `message`, it displays "swim use com.apple.inputmethod.SCIM".

Comment: I have tried to check with a message but I never see any message, nor anything in message buffer.